# Iframe is srcdoc not updating when using variable

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Variables don't work for my iframe's srcdoc or you can't use div.value or something.When I use a variable for an iframe's srcdoc the iframe's html(srcdoc) doesn't update. This code is from me trying to make a code editor. Please Help, I am okay with using jQuery.
It's not done

```js
const html = document.getElementById("html");
const css = document.getElementById("css");
const js = document.getElementById("js");
var edH = document.getElementById("edH");
var edC = document.getElementById("edC");
var edJ = document.getElementById("edJ");
var ifr = document.getElementById("res");
var cssCode;
var htmlCode;
var jsCode;

html.addEventListener("click", changeHTML);
css.addEventListener("click", changeCss);
js.addEventListener("click", changeJs);
html.addEventListener("keydown", update);
function changeHTML() {
  htmlCode = edH.value;
  jsCode = edJ.value;
  cssCode = edC.value;
  edH.value = htmlCode;
  edH.style.display = "block";
  edC.style.display = "none";
  edJ.style.display = "none";
}

function changeCss() {
  htmlCode = edH.value;
  jsCode = edJ.value;
  cssCode = edC.value;
  edC.value = cssCode;
  edC.style.display = "block";
  edH.style.display = "none";
  edJ.style.display = "none";
}

function changeJs() {
  htmlCode = edH.value;
  jsCode = edJ.value;
  cssCode = edC.value;
  edJ.style.display = "block";
  edC.style.display = "none";
  edH.style.display = "none";
}

function update() {
  ifr.srcdoc = edH.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tab" class="tabs">
      <p class="langs" id="lang">
        <span id="html">HTML</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span id="css">CSS</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span id="js">Javascript</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="edH" class="edH" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="edC" class="edC" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="edJ" class="edJ" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <iframe id="res" width="500px" height="200px"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

the iframe's srcdoc will not update to edH.value.
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-haze-m95ht3
Thanks.

Comment: You're adding a keydown event listener to a span; there's no where to type in a span.

Comment: im so dumb, can you make an answer with this so I can make that the answer. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a keydown event listener to a span; there's no where to type in a span.